# PHP: modulo result truncates into two digits

Tags: php

I am just wondering why in PHP when I `echo` the modulo of `123.456` and `100`, the result is only `23`, but the quotient of `123.456 / 100` is `1.23456`. For instance:

```
 <?php
    echo 123.456 % 100;
    echo 123.456 / 100;
 ?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
 23
 1.23456
```

I am expecting that it should return the complete decimal places which is `23456`, but it round it off into two decimal places instead. I am new to PHP, and I have no idea if this is a normal behavior of `modulo`. And if it is, is there any way to get my expected result?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: [`For non-integers you need to use fmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function of PHP. And modulus value of `123.456 % 100` is `23.456` and its working fine. [Check Here](https://3v4l.org/M8GGf) also [google it](https://www.google.co.in/#q=123.456+%25+100). It seems you don't have an idea about how modulus work whats the mathematical logic behind it

Comment: Hi @Uchiha, thanks for pointing  that out. :)

Answer (score -1):

What if you force it to be float?

```
echo (float)(123.456 % 100);
```

The problem seems to be that it's parsing it as an integer.